# Featured-Content/Featured Posts With Random Order

Tags: order, featured-post

I am working on dailysuit.de, which features four featured posts at the top, defined by a certain tag. The order is newest to oldest.

**How do I get this order randomised (and not newest to oldest)?**

I tried to change something like the following in inc/featured-content.php:

```
// Query for featured posts.
$featured = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => $settings['quantity'],
        'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => $tag,
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

to

```
// Query for featured posts.
$featured = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => $settings['quantity'],
        'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => $tag,
            ),
        ),
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
    ) );
```

but there are two flaws:

**1. It did not work/randomise.**

**2. Changing this file is a bad idea. If the theme gets an update, the randomising is gone.**

Is there a working solution having it in a child theme? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Third party themes are off topic, but I ended up checking it anyway:*

### The Problem

What comes before & after your posted code is important:

**Before:**

```
// Return array of cached results if they exist.
$featured_ids = get_transient( 'featured_content_ids' );
if ( ! empty( $featured_ids ) ) {
    return array_map( 'absint', (array) $featured_ids );
}
```

**After:**

```
// Ensure correct format before save/return.
$featured_ids = wp_list_pluck( (array) $featured, 'ID' );
$featured_ids = array_map( 'absint', $featured_ids );
set_transient( 'featured_content_ids', $featured_ids );
```

This means your theme is caching the featured post IDs, through the Transients API.

So randomizing will not work like you expected.

The default TTL is 0, meaning it will never expire, until it's deleted by hand.

### Workarounds

Here are four different methods:

**Method 1)**

Instead, modify this in `Featured_Content::get_featured_posts()`:

```
$featured_posts = get_posts( array(
        'include'        => $post_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => count( $post_ids ),
) );
```

to:

```
$featured_posts = get_posts( array(
        'include'        => $post_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => count( $post_ids ),
        'orderby'        => 'rand'
) );
```

within your child theme.

**Method 2)**

We could also shuffle the posts with the `longform_get_featured_posts` filter:

```
add_filter( 'longform_get_featured_posts', function( $posts )
{
    shuffle( $posts );
    return $posts;
}, 11 );
```

**Method 3)**

We could modify the `orderby` within the `pre_get_posts` hook:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q )
{
    if( 
           did_action( 'longform_featured_posts_before' ) 
        && ! did_action( 'longform_featured_posts_after' ) 
    )
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );            
}, 99 );
```

between the `longform_featured_posts_before` and `longform_featured_posts_after` hooks.

**Method 4)**

We could try to increase the theme's `quantity` option (from the backend) to 6 but display only 4 (just as an example). We could then use a modification of method #2:

```
add_filter( 'longform_get_featured_posts', function( $posts )
{
    shuffle( $posts );

    if( count( $posts ) > 4  )
        $posts = array_slice( $posts, 0, 4 );

    return $posts;
}, 11 );
```

To increase the number above `6`, then `max_posts` need to be modified from this code part:

```
// Add support for featured content.
add_theme_support( 'featured-content', array(
    'featured_content_filter' => 'longform_get_featured_posts',
    'max_posts' => 6,
) );
```

Many other variations could be possible, but I stop here ;-)

*Note that I've never installed or used this theme before. These are just some ideas based on skimming through the theme's [source code](https://github.com/cohhe/longform).*

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, but I am not so sure, where to find "Featured_Content::get_featured_posts():". In the child theme there was no file having that code inserted.

Comment: Okay, I found that line in inc/featured-content.php within the original/mother theme. If I change the code there, it will be gone on the next update. If I duplicate this directory and file to the child theme, it does not work, I believe. I tried it last week with a different issue.

Comment: I updated the answer with another (untested) option, that you could add to your `functions.php` file, to test @vega

Comment: Nice idea. I tried that, but does not work, it seems, after testing with STRG + F5.

Comment: I modified the priority for the second method @vega

Comment: Oh, great, man, that seems to work now, BUT there is a big "flaw": It does shuffle always only the 4 ones, that are shown, but there are like 20 featured posts and I guess, this solution randomises only the output (4 featured posts) instead of the whole featured posts. :\

Comment: Now I remember, why I tried to hook directly into the function. Shit. :( In other words it randomises only the newest 4 featured posts and not all of those, having the tag to get into featured posts.

Comment: We should keep the language polite here ;-) Finally I provide you with the third method, that might help randomize all featured post ids. @vega

Comment: Ah, sorry, my language was not meant in an unpolite matter. :) And your third method does the same as the second, just shuffling the output of the 4 featured posts. :\

Comment: I added the 4th method, in the case the featured ids are sliced down before being cached. There are other possibilities but they require more theme-info or customized solutions, so I stop now, hopefully it helps ;-) @vega

Comment: Great to hear that, you're welcome ;-) @vega